# Where are the ice rings in X-ray crystallography located?

Tags: water, crystals, data-analysis, ice, x-rays

I threw this image of one of my protein crystal's diffraction pattern (not the greatest) on a poster, and was wondering where (what reciprocal dimension) the ice rings are located as it might be a useful reference (or talking point).

While I can find information about water ice's unit cell parameters (4.5 Å, 7.3 Å), I'm not sure if these are where the reflections would be located (the inner two rings seem far too close for that disparity, and I believe the outer two rings are at a much higher resolution (< 3 Å)

[image]

Comment: Is this off-topic or otherwise bad for Physics.SE?

Comment: No, I think this is a great question. The downvote is odd, because if there is a good reason for it, it is certainly not an obvious reason.

Comment: I assume that somebody didn't like a question with no mention of string theory or symmetry groups. :)

Comment: I didn't DV, but I can see why - the "ice rings" are more properly called "DeBye-Scherrer" rings, and their precise location will depend on the wavelength of the incident radiation.  Further, the diffractograms are typically pictures of reciprocal space, so discussing the d-spacing of ice on a reciprocal space map requires some basic calculation, but it is not evident from the picture which map is used. So, question at its heart is a good one, but as written is riddled with errors.

Comment: Jen described the reasons for my downvote very well. No geometry of this "poster", no wavelenth, just hope others will do the thinking for him.

Comment: @Jen while they may properly be called something else, common parlance for these artifacts in macromolecular x-ray crystallography is indeed "ice rings".  If you believe my question could be improved, please do so, a good question is just as important as an answer.

Comment: @Georg, I lack the knowledge on how to predict where in recip-space reflections should lie given some lattice.  If I knew how to do it, why ask a question?  Granted, this question is one of practice, not theory.  Also, you suggest that the wavelength matters, which I was unaware of.  I know that higher energy x-rays will diffract at a higher angle (Bragg's law), but that would just scale the entire diffractogram...  If I'm missing something that's probably another question.

Comment: @NickT - just what do you think your map is here?

Comment: @Jen, my diffraction pattern?  It's a set of sharp reflections over half a degree mucked up by a bunch of randomly ordered water ice.

Answer (score 5):

I finally found a source; according to [Peter Nollert](http://www.emeraldbiosystems.com/blog/post/5-Rules-of-Crystal-Cryopreservation-for-X-ray-Diffraction.aspx), ice rings are located at:

- 3.897 Å,
- 3.669 Å,
- 3.441 Å,
- 2.671 Å, and
- 2.249 Å.

My frame seems to be missing one of the three 3 Å rings, but the 2 Å rings seem plausible.